# Jquery onclick doesnt work to IE7

Tags: jquery, onclick, getelementbyid, attr

This is my code. It works to Firefox, Chrome but not in ie7.

arr makes (number + 1) for every line..

```
$("#div-id1 a").attr("onclick", function (arr) {
  return "document.getElementById('row1').value+=" + arr;
});
$("#div-id2 a").attr("onclick", function (arr) {
  return "document.getElementById('row2').value+=" + arr;
});

<input id="row1"  type="text" name="row1" value="" />
<input id="row2"  type="text" name="row2" value="" />
```

My js codes are between this.

```
jQuery(function($){...code...});
```

I am adding onclick, because links are looking like this.

`<a>Hello World</a>`

Code output is :

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('row1').value+=1">Hello World</a>
```

Can someone show me working example ?

Comment: Why are you setting the attribute? Just use `$('#div-id1 a').click(function(){ ... });` and to get the value, `$('#row1').val()`

Answer (score 4):

You're doing it wrong.

Will adding a function to the `onclick` attribute work? yes, in some browsers, but you're not making good use of jQuery's normalized events. The jQuery way of setting a click event is to use `click(fn)`, or `bind('click', fn)` or `live('click', fn)`

Additionally, since you haven't shown where your script is in relation to the HTML, it's possible that the dom elements dont exist yet. Using `live` will delegate the event to the document so that it continues to detect new elements that match the selector. Alternatively you could use the `document ready` event:

Long form:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){...code...});
```

Short form:

```
jQuery(function($){...code...});
```

For more info you should read the [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Put it into a `$(document).ready(...`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div-id1 a").attr("onclick", function (arr) {
      return "document.getElementById('row1').value+=" + arr;
    });
    $("#div-id2 a").attr("onclick", function (arr) {
      return "document.getElementById('row2').value+=" + arr;
    });
});
```

Please read http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 2):

Don't set attribute onclick - pass a function to the jquery click function

```
$("#div-id1 a").click( function () {
    /* Code here */
});
```

Can you explain further about arr though? You would need to make some modifications to the code to make it work with click instead of attr.